# Fill entire table row in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-tables

How can I fill (with `background-color`) an entire table row when I have a table with different numbers of columns in each row?

I have a table like this:

[image]

But I want to color the entire line to the end, like this (with the same color, not yellow):

[image]

Now, I am trying to do it like this:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
```

Comment: Post a complete code example with your HTML and all relevant CSS please.

Comment: Many of us cannot see the images. Try to post the actual code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnsLeqnu/
I want to color the entire first line to the end

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. Post a complete code example with your HTML and all relevant CSS please *in your question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `colspan` on the last `td` for row 1 and 2, or else it won't stretch to full table width.

```css
table, body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: top;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td#naglowek {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

td:first-child {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
 background-color: Red;
}

td {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

th {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: solid 0px black;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Imie</td>
            <td colspan='3'>Wartosc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nazwisko</td>
            <td colspan='3'>Wartosc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adres</td>
            <td><b>Kraj</b></td>
            <td><b>Województwo</b></td>
            <td><b>Miejscowość</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

**Update**

Based on your comments where a solution without the need of empty `td` and `colspan` and after some thinking, I came up with this trick, which could be an alternative, though you need to test it in all major browsers to make sure it works (I tested it on Windows using Chrome, FF, Edge, IE11 with success).

```css
table, body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: top;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td#naglowek {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

td:first-child {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

td {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

th {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: solid 0px black;
    text-align: left;
}

/* begin - fix for full width background color */
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:first-child {
  position: relative;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:first-child:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* end - fix for full width background color */
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Imie</td>
            <td>Wartosc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nazwisko</td>
            <td>Wartosc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adres</td>
            <td><b>Kraj</b></td>
            <td><b>Województwo</b></td>
            <td><b>Miejscowość</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
            <td>Wartość</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Yes, but without the addition of empty <td></td>

Comment: I have a lot of rows with different number of column. How can i do this without the addition of empty <td></td> and without adding colspan in each row, which has a different number of columns?

Comment: @malymakar You can't

Comment: @malymakar Well, ... you can, kind of, came up with a trick without the need of empty td and colspan ... updated my answer

Comment: This is what I meant. Thank you very much. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add the [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) attribute to your table rows where the rows have less than the full number of cells. For example `<td colspan="3">Wartosc</td>`:

```css
table,
body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-align: top;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td#naglowek {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
td:first-child {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: Red;
}
td {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
th {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: solid 0px black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Imie</td>
    <td colspan="3">Wartosc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nazwisko</td>
    <td>Wartosc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adres</td>
    <td><b>Kraj</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Województwo</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Miejscowość</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Wartość</td>
    <td>Wartość</td>
    <td>Wartość</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```